# Get plain text from HTML in .NET

Tags: .net, html, string

What is the best way to get a plain text string from an HTML string?

```
public string GetPlainText(string htmlString)
{
    // any .NET built in utility?
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by plain text?

Comment: @slandau: I want to output readable text from an HTML input. I'm not sure if something additional to remove the tags...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's no built in utility as far as I know, but depending on your requirements you could use Regular Expressions to strip out all of the tags:

```
string htmlString = @"<p>I'm HTML!</p>";
Regex.Replace(htmlString, @"<(.|\n)*?>", "");
```

Comment: check this epic question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Andrey Haha that's a pretty awesome accepted answer. Luckily the OP didn't state exact requirements nor define the HTML string so this should catch most actual HTML cases, rather than XHTML.

Comment: Regex still doesn't necessarily yield final result. You need to convert *at least* `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`.  If your text contains other HTML character entities like `&scaron;` (š) you need to decode all of them as well.

Answer (score 46):

You can use MSHTML, which can be pretty forgiving;

```
//using microsoft.mshtml
HTMLDocument htmldoc = new HTMLDocument();
IHTMLDocument2 htmldoc2 = (IHTMLDocument2)htmldoc;
htmldoc2.write(new object[] { "<p>Plateau <i>of<i> <b>Leng</b><hr /><b erp=\"arp\">2 sugars please</b> <xxx>what? &amp; who?" });

string txt = htmldoc2.body.outerText;
```

> Plateau of Leng 2 sugars please what?
>   & who?

Comment: Works like a charm! Should be the accepted answer. Note that you need to add reference to `Microsoft.mshtml.dll` first.

Comment: Are you sure this method is safe with HTML from untrusted sources? Does HTMLDocument.Write() execute passed scripts?

Comment: This answer is far more robust than the accepted answer (that uses just simple regex to remove tags) and is probably necessary for pages with any reasonable complexity.

Comment: @giladmayani You could use the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19414886/1911540 to strip out any `<script>` tags (and their inner contents) before using this method. This would also lead to downstream string operation performance increases as the Javascript contents can be quite lengthy.

Comment: @SpecialSauce that is true, but don't forget that technically, Javascript can exist not only in `<script>` tags, E.G as attribute values:
<button onclick="someJavascript();">

Comment: This is an under-appreciated, simple solution, particularly for generating the plain text content from an html email.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>There is no built-in solution in the framework.</strike>

If you need to parse HTML I made good experience using a library called [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).
It parses an HTML file and provides access to it by DOM, similar to the XML classes.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I found a combination of regex and HttpUtility to be the best and shortest solution.

```
Return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(
                Regex.Replace(HtmlString, "<(.|\n)*?>", "")
                )
```

This removes all the tags, and then decodes any of the extras like `&lt;` or `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't .NET built in method to do it. But, like pointed by @rudi_visser, it can be done with *Regular Expressions*.

If you need to remove more than just the tags (i.e., turn **&acirc;** to **â**), you can use a more elaborated solution, like found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/HTML_to_Plain_Text.aspx).