# Get inner html text from node

Tags: c#, html, html-editor

How to convert html editor text to Plain text during data loading from database

I hava a HTML Data :

```
 " <p style="margin: 0px; text-align: justify;"><span style="color: #000000; 
font-family: droid serif, serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: 
start;">Inadequate storm-water drainage </span><span style="color: #ff0000; 
font-family: droid serif, serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: start;">"
```

But, Expected 
"Inadequate storm-water drainage"

How can i do it.

Comment: You could use an xml parser.

Comment: @NtFreX xml parser on HTML often causes problems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get plain text from HTML in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870438/get-plain-text-from-html-in-net)

Comment: @NtFreX HTML isn't XML. You can't use an XML parser.

Comment: Expected why? What did you try? Have you tried using a Regex? HTML parsing? Something?

Comment: Yes. I tried with Regex. But It's not working.

Comment: @ShahanaAkterPingkey you can use HtmlAgilityPack with its ConvertToPlainText() method